# How to name model's foreignkey field in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

In `Django`, I can name each field of model like this(In Korean):

```
description = models.CharField("설명", max_length=100, blank=True)
image = ImageField("이미지", upload_to=upload_location)
```

but in case of `ForeignKey`, it doesn't work.

```
album = models.ForeignKey("앨범", Album)
```

Why does it not work only on `ForeignKey`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the first parameter of a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) is the model it is linking to, this can be a string such as `'self'` which is why it allows strings.

If you want to specify a `verbose_name` then you should use the keyword arg

```
album = models.ForeignKey(Album, verbose_name="앨범")
```

For more on `verbose_names`, see the [docs for Verbose field names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names)

> `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField` and `OneToOneField` require the first argument to be a model class, so use the verbose_name keyword argument: